# Least disruptive way to download file using PhP. Prevent disrupting of ongoing updating of it

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on a website in which it would be useful to to allow a user the option of downloading the content of a file, even when it's going to be updated by another user at the same time or later.

My problem is that the solution I've tried so far allows downloading, but will disrupt any later updating of the file. I don't think I can represent the code relating to the updating concisely (it is spread over multiple files), except that it's through AJAXing the data (which I'm not sure why it would cause this problem). In case it's relevant, this is a file which gets updated multiple times.

When I use fireftp I can download the file without disrupting this process, which makes me optimistic there's a PhP solution. I am currently downloading the data by Ajaxing the file contents to the page the "downloading user" is on. The code for this (within php) is:

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents ($_POST['file'])); //file address comes through Ajax POST request.
echo ($file_contents); //to access the content client side
```

Is there another way to access the text/content within a file without any unintended consequences on other server processing of it?

Comment: So I would be downloading a _partial_ file only in some situations then? What sense could that possible make? What type of file/data are we talking about here - text, images, multimedia, ...? What file sizes, what frequency of down- and uploads?

Comment: And how exactly does the uploading part work? It can’t be a “standard” HTML form/PHP file upload, since you’re accessing the file data using $_POST …?

Comment: It's a csv file, in which a row is added one at a time after each time the user completes a question/task. 
The rate of change can vary, but often is updated within 10 seconds, until generally 50+ tasks or questions are completed.

Comment: Which uploading are you referring to? The code I've put in is when someone wants to access the csv file that has been created. This is done through Ajax.

Comment: Sorry, I though by “updating” the file you meant file uploads by users. // Does it have to be a “file”? Why not store this data in a database instead - and write a function that reads the current records and _makes_ them “downloadable” in CSV format?

Comment: It would require rewriting a lot of the code that's lined up to writing the data in csvs - but that would address the issue (so I think I'll do that in the long term). //It would be nice to have a short term solution though - accessing a file using PhP shouldn't necessarily disrupt other php processing of it - right?

Comment: Well that depends on the specifics, how you are adding stuff to the file (what mode is it opened in), whether some kind of locking is involved, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156080/discussion-between-anthony-haffey-and-cbroe).

Comment: Found the error: reading a file - for some reason - has triggered something that changes the read/write permissions of it (i.e. denied permission)! I seem to have fixed this by changing the permissions with a chmod($path_to_file,0644) in the code just before it tries to update the file.

Comment: Please do not "replace" questions. Delete this one and ask a new one.

Comment: @AndreyS Scherbakov - sorry, I was breaking the rules by editing the question on this website rather than asking a new one. Would you mind reposting your solution here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/184743/dynamic-way-to-use-array-as-index-in-javascript